# Replace character string elements by indices efficiently in R

Tags: regex, string, r, replace

I would like to **efficiently** replace elements in my `character` object with other particular elements in particular places (these places are indices which I know as they are results of the `gregexpr` function).

I would like some `foo` function that works like:

```
foo("qwerty", c(1,3,5), c("z", "x", "y"))
```

giving me:

```
[1] "zwxryy"
```

I searched the `stringr` package cran pdf but nothing hit my mind. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
xx <- unlist(strsplit("qwerty",""))
xx[c(1,3,5)] <- c("z", "x", "y")
paste0(xx,collapse='')
[1] "zwxryy"
```

Comment: Ok, I see you've already posted it, so you probably should modify it to something  like `foo <- function(a,b,c){
  temp <- strsplit(a, "")[[1]];
  temp[b] <- c;
  paste0(temp, collapse = "")
}` to fit OPs rquirments

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the one below, if you don't have that many characters to replace

```
  st1 <- "qwerty"
 gsub("^.(.).(.).","z\\1x\\2y", st1)
#[1] "zwxryy"
```

Answer (score 0):

In `stringi` package there is `stri_sub` function that works like this:

```
a <- "12345"
stri_sub(a, from=c(1,3,5),len=1) <- letters[c(1,3,5)]
a
## [1] "a2345" "12c45" "1234e"
```

it's almost what you want. Just use this in loop:

```
a <- "12345"
for(i in c(1,3,5)){
    stri_sub(a, from=i,len=1) <- letters[i] 
}
a
## [1] "a2c4e"
```

Be aware that this kind of function is on our TODO list, check:
https://github.com/Rexamine/stringi/issues?state=open